# Foreach Loop and if statement using PHP

Tags: php

I want to edit a JSON object, so made method called `alterJSON` the function find the specific JSON `array` from the database and then change the `key-values` based on the parameters was given
so my question is as you can see in this foreach loop  there is an `(if statement)`

```
foreach( $decoded as $index => $product ){
                    print_r('<pre>');
                    if( $product->$key == $item) {
                        echo ('found');
                        $decoded[ $index ]->$key = $value;
                        $json = json_encode( $decoded );
                        
                        $stmt->execute([
                            ':json' =>  $json,
                            ':id'   =>  $bid
                        ]);
                    }                   
                }
```

the loop will print `found` and make some changes on the `$JSON` by `MySQL` query and that's perfectly working, but it will only find the JSON `object or item` even if there are more then one `item` in the same `key-value` so, I want to make another condition in the `statement` that checks a unique `key-value`
called `id` so how can I accomplish that? I made some attempts and failed.

what I have tried

```
<?php
public function AlterJSON( $bid=false, $item=false, $key=false, $Product, $id, $value=false ){
        try{
            if( $bid && $item && $key && $value && $Product && $this->connected === true ){
                
                $stmt=$this->connection->prepare('select `items` from `bills` where `id`=:id');
                $stmt->execute( [ ':id' => $bid ] );
                
                $fetched = $stmt->fetchColumn();
                $decoded = json_decode( $fetched );
                
                $stmt=$this->connection->prepare('update `bills` set `items`=:json where id=:id');
                
                
                foreach( $decoded as $index => $product ){
                    print_r('<pre>');
                    if( $product->$key == $item  && $product->$id == $Product) {
                        echo ('found');
                        $decoded[ $index ]->$key = $value;
                        $json = json_encode( $decoded );
                        
                        $stmt->execute([
                            ':json' =>  $json,
                            ':id'   =>  $bid
                        ]);
                    }                   
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        } catch( PDOException $e ){
            return $this->errors === true ? $this->error( $e->getMessage() ) : false;
        }
    }
?>
```

`function call:-`

```
    $call =  $dbConnection->AlterJSON( $BillID, $CurrentPrice,'price', $ProductID,'id', $ProductPrice );
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `$product->id == $id` instead? and wouldn't you think it would be easier to delegate this in another table making the id just a foreign key, instead of saving the whole json string, decoding and encoding and whatnot

Comment: What is $item from here `if( $product->$key == $item)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to simply put the `$stmt=$this->connection->prepare` into the `foreach` loop?

Just be sure, the function `AlterJSON` have a variable `$Product` but when you call this `AlterJSON` you use `$ProductID`, can you use `$ProductID` for both two variables? The PHP is case sensitive for variables. So it's good, but I for the readable it's better.

And other trick in `if( $product->$key` if `$key` not exist in `$product` will produce an error. Yeah, you have a try catch, but if the replacement is in N loop you will lose the possibility of this update. I would install protection before the `$product->$key` to just be sure the key exists.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the $ProductID is a  `Post` value it contains an `integer` that exists in the Json what i want to do is check if the `Price = $item` and `Id = $ProductID`